# android textview settext is not displayed

Tags: android, textview, settext

Im facing a problem. After running app , the textview I set is not displayed. This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final TextView rangeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.range_label);
final TextView beaconMacAddressLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_mac_address_label);
final TextView beaconUuidLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_uuid_label);
final TextView beaconVersionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_major_minor_label);
final TextView beaconStatsLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_stats_label);

rangeLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
rangeLabel.setText(R.string.question_mark);
region = new Region("regionid", null, null, null);

beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
beaconManager.setRangingListener(new RangingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                  if (!beacons.isEmpty()) {

                      Beacon closestBeacon = beacons.get(0);

                      beaconMacAddressLabel.setText(getString(R.string.mac_address) + " : " + closestBeacon.getMacAddress());
                      beaconUuidLabel.setText(closestBeacon.getProximityUUID());
                      beaconVersionLabel.setText(getString(R.string.major) + ": "+closestBeacon.getMajor() +
                                                 "   " + getString(R.string.minor) + ": " + closestBeacon.getMinor());

                      beaconStatsLabel.setText(getString(R.string.power) + ": " +
                                            closestBeacon.getMeasuredPower() +
                                            " " +
                                            getString(R.string.dbm) +
                                            " |  " +
                                            getString(R.string.rssi) + 
                                            ": " + closestBeacon.getRssi());

                      double accuracy = Utils.computeAccuracy(closestBeacon);

                      switch (Utils.proximityFromAccuracy(accuracy)) {
                        case FAR:
                            rangeLabel.setText(R.string.cold);
                            rangeLabel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cold_colour));
                            rangeLabel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cold_indicator_background);
                            break;
                        case NEAR:
                            rangeLabel.setText(R.string.warm);
                            rangeLabel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.warm_colour));
                            rangeLabel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.warm_indicator_background);
                            break;
                        case IMMEDIATE:
                            rangeLabel.setText(R.string.hot);
                            rangeLabel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hot_colour));
                            rangeLabel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hot_indicator_background);
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            rangeLabel.setText(R.string.question_mark);
                            rangeLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            rangeLabel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_background);
                            break;
```

is there anything wrong in mycode? only the title(set in XML) and rangelable(set at line 10) are displayed. None of other. anyone know why? 
Ive tried to change color but no help. Guess there something wrong with my code

in case needed, this is my XML:

https://github.com/KarlNosworthy/hotwarmcold/blob/master/HotWarmColdApp/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: Did you try logging beacons.size() in case the !beacons.empty() condition is not being met?

Answer (score 0):

looks like Range label is centered in the middle of the screen.
it's probably covering the other labels

try hiding it to see if you you see the other labels.
and I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. but you might want to user LinearLayout instead of relative...